# cumsum with several groups and nonconsecutive dates

Tags: r

I have this situation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
    date = c(
          as.Date("2015-3-1")
        , as.Date("2015-1-1")
        , as.Date("2015-5-1")
    )
    ,cat1 = as.factor(c("cat11","cat11","cat11"))
    ,cat2 = as.factor(c("cat21","cat21","cat21"))
    ,x = c(1,2,3)  
)
```

I would like to calculate the cumulative sum of x for each cat1 x cat2 combination in the order of the dates (2 => 3 => 6 for combination). This is what I tried:

```
df %>%
    group_by(
        date
        , cat1
        , cat2
    ) %>%
    arrange(
        date,
        cat1,
        cat2 
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        cumsum_x = cumsum(x)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

The wrong result is:

[image]

Could someone please be so and suggest a solution? Please note, that this should work for more category combination and the cumulative sum should be calculated for each combination separately based on the order of the potentially non consecutive dates.

Comment: Remove `date` from `group_by` statement.  Let ut be in arrange only

Comment: @AnilGoyal  thanks could you possibly be a bit more helpful - I already use arrange ...

Comment: Try the code suggested.  Actually i am away from my machine that's why I cannot check it now, but it should work.

Comment: Do you want to fill in for missing dates too?

Comment: Thanks not sure what you mean be missing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
    group_by(cat1
        , cat2
    ) %>%
    arrange(
        date
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        cumsum_x = cumsum(x)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks looks promising .. will try in prod.